# symfony generate module, which shows fatal error

Tags: php, linux, symfony1, module

Hi am trying to generae module user in symfony using command
php symfony doctrine:generate-module --with-show --non-verbose-templates frontend user User

...but it shows fatal error as

> Class 'UserForm' not found in
>   /home/pushparaj/sfprojects/educonnect/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/generator/sfModelGenerator.class.php
>   on 331

pls give proper solution for this..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you build all your models? Try **./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes** first.

Comment: ya i got the solution...i build model and sql seperately and dint build form...tats d prob..thanks for u r reply